# If/elif/else statements

Tags: python

My program/project is about asking the user if hes tall enough to ride a roller coaster and providing statements for a "yes" or "no" answer. My problem is if the user enters something other than yes or no I want it to say, "Enter yes or no please." My code works until I try and insert that statement. How do I insert that statement without having errors.

```
rc1 = input('Are you tall enough to ride this roller coaster? ')
if rc1 == 'no':
    print('Please exit the ride!')
elif rc1 == 'yes':
    rc2 = int(input('How tall are you? '))
if rc2 <= 119:
    print('You are not tall enough for this ride!')
else:
    print('Enter and enjoy the ride!')
```

Comment: You might want to indent the second `if` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a couple quick things.  Just like above, a while loop is a good way to go to keep prompting a user until you get input in your desired format and your rc2 variable is defined within the if statement and not available for the comparison so it needs to be defined earlier so it is available to your second conditional.  Something like this:

```
rc1 = input('Are you tall enough to ride this roller coaster? ')
rc2 = 0
while str.lower(rc1) not in ('yes', 'no'):
    print('Please answer yes or no')
    rc1 = input('Are you tall enough to ride this roller coaster? ')
if rc1 == 'no':
    print('Please exit the ride!')
elif rc1 == 'yes':
    rc2 = int(input('How tall are you? '))
if rc2 <= 119:
    print('You are not tall enough for this ride!')
else:
    print('Enter and enjoy the ride!')
```

Comment: This code works, thank you. One quick question, what does str.lower do?

Comment: Good question!  str.lower converts a string (user input in this example) to all lowercase to compare is against the values given.  This way if a user inputs Yes, it is automatically using all lowercase before comparing it to the yes or no values.  Your user might get confused if they wrote Yes or No as input and are told it is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a while loop and would look something like following:

```py
answer = None
rc2 = None
while answer not in ("yes", "no"):
    answer = input('Are you tall enough to ride this roller coaster? ')
    if answer == "yes":
        rc2 = int(input('How tall are you? '))
    elif answer == "no":
        print('Please exit the ride!')
    else:
        print("Please enter yes or no.")
    
if rc2 <= 119:
    print('You are not tall enough for this ride!')
else:
    print('Enter and enjoy the ride!')
```

Comment: You might get away with that in Python 2. In Python 3, you will get a `TypeError`.

Comment: The answer for no is Please exit the ride but the code breaks after.

Comment: @Godfist Yes that is because it tries to use `<=` to compare `None` with an int. Probably the whole of that last `if` block needs to be inside an `if rc2 is not None:` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
rc1 = input('Are you tall enough to ride this roller coaster? ')
rc2 = None
if rc1 == 'no':
    print('Please exit the ride!')
elif rc1 == 'yes':
    rc2 = int(input('How tall are you? '))
if rc2 != None:
    if rc2 <= 119:
        print('You are not tall enough for this ride!')
    else:
        print('Enter and enjoy the ride!')
```

OR

```
rc1 = input('Are you tall enough to ride this roller coaster? ')
if rc1 == 'no':
    print('Please exit the ride!')
elif rc1 == 'yes':
    rc2 = int(input('How tall are you? '))
    if rc2 <= 119:
        print('You are not tall enough for this ride!')
    else:
        print('Enter and enjoy the ride!')
```

You have to initialize the `rc2` variable at the beginning. The reason you got the error was because the program was checking if `rc2` was less than or equal to 119 when it didn't even know what the variable was. `rc2` only exists when `rc1` equals yes. For it to be used afterwards, `rc2` must exist, regardless of condition.

Comment: Thanks for answering but you missed the original question about inserting an "Enter yes or no" if the user doesn't answer yes or no. The original code already works.

Answer (score 0):

I also got a quick cleaner solution working on it more than i should have lol. Thank you for the help

```
rc1 = input('Are you tall enough to ride this roller coaster? ')
while rc1 not in ('yes', 'no'):
    print('Please enter yes or no.' )
    rc1 = input('Are you tall enough to ride this roller coaster? ')
if rc1 == 'no':
    print('Please exit the ride!')
elif rc1 == 'yes':
    rc2 = int(input('How tall are you? '))
    if rc2 <= 119:
        print('You are not tall enough for this ride!')
    else:
        print('Enter and enjoy the ride!')
```